# Large parallel corpus of English and Farsi text

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

hope you are doing well.
I am looking for a large parallel corpus of English and Farsi text, professionally written or edited. I would be more than happy to have your suggestions.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the criteria you give (large, parallel, professionally written or edited) there is probably just one such corpus: The [Multilingual Bible Parallel Corpus](http://christos-c.com/bible/), for a more formal reference see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10579-014-9287-y). It has its limitations: The texts belong to a very specific register and genre, and they lack a lot of modern terminology (no airplanes nor bicycles occur there).

An alternative may be the [JW corpus](https://aclanthology.org/P19-1310/) created from a crawl of the website of Jehova's Witnesses. Again, this corpus contains religious material, but its source is written in modern English and it contains a higher proportion of modern vocabulary. I cannot assess the degree of professionality that has gone in the Farsi texts collected from that site.

Comment: Thank you so much.
And what if we discard the professionally written/edited criteria, would we get more results? Do you know any?